# mysql - cant specify target table for update in from clause

Tags: mysql, select

I have such a query:

```
UPDATE `user` 
SET mail='abc@abc' 
WHERE id = 
    IF((SELECT admin FROM user WHERE id = '1') > 2, 
       (SELECT id FROM user WHERE id='2'), 
       (SELECT id FROM user WHERE id = '1')
      )
```

as a result I get error message:

> "You can't specify target table 'user' for update in FROM clause"

I want tu update column named 'mail' in all rows from 'user' table where 'id' of row is 1 or 2 depending on value of another column named 'admin'. Please help with corect syntax.

Comment: dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE `user`
SET email='abc@abc'
WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM (SELECT IF((SELECT admin FROM user WHERE id = '1') > 2,
                                      (SELECT id FROM user WHERE id = '2'),
                                      (SELECT id FROM user WHERE id = '1')) AS id
                           ) AS t
           );
```

Answer (score 0):

1. when using same table multiple times in a query, you need to use aliases:

   SELECT * FROM users u1 INNER JOIN users u2 ON ...
2. whats the point of those sub-selects?
   for example, isn't this part "(SELECT id FROM user WHERE id='2')" equal to just writing "2" ?

Comment: value id=2 is just an example. Value 2 in this example changes depeneding on user login values stored in session.

Comment: @Kalreg: O.K., but it's a nonsensical example. `SELECT id FROM user WHERE id = example_value_stored_in_session` is always either `example_value_stored_in_session` or `NULL`.

Comment: @Kalreg: yes, but selecting an **id** for a record for which you already know the id is pointless... ;)

Comment: my query is a little more complex, so it doesnt seem pointless. I just made it more basic for putting it all easier to answer :)